# how to split dataframe into multiple dataframe which the number of line is equal and export xls files?

Tags: python, pandas

**Input**

```
    id 
    1
    2
    3
    4
    5
    6
    7
    8
    9
    10
    ……
```

**Trying**

```
def split_equal(f,number_of_chunks):
    df=pd.read_excel(f,encoding='gbk')
    number_of_chunks=len(df)//number_of_chunks
    for id, df_i in  enumerate(np.array_split(df, number_of_chunks)):
        df_i.to_excel('f_{id}.xls'.format(id=id),index=False)
```

For example, I want to splited dataframe which the number line is 1000 and if the line of rest is less than 1000, it still returns the smaller files.

If the length of df is 25314, it returns 1014 lines into smaller dataframe by my function. I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: I believe you are getting the 1014 because your function is enforcing how many chunks you want rather than the size of each chunk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go =^..^=

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx')


def split(df, lines_number):
    if lines_number < df.shape[0]:
        for i in range(0, int(df.shape[0]/lines_number) + 1, 1):
            new_df = df.iloc[i*lines_number:i*lines_number+lines_number]
            new_df.to_excel('file_' + str(i) + '_.xls', index=False)


lines_number = 10
split(df, lines_number)
```